# java basics about String

Tags: java, string

To what value is a variable of the String type automatically initialized?

Answer (score 7):

`null`

Unless it's inside a method (local variable), in which case it's not declared to anything.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a summary of the answers posted by [Martin v. Löwis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353264/java-basics-about-string/1353270#1353270) and [silky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353264/java-basics-about-string/1353268#1353268).

We can say the following about the initialization of a `String` object:

- If the `String` is a local variable, it will not be initialized.
- If the `String` is a class variable, instance variable, or an array component, then it will be initialized to `null`.

---

The reasoning is as follows:

As a variable with the type of [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a reference type, according to [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third%5Fedition/html/j3TOC.html), [Section 4.12.5: Initial Values of Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5) says the following:

> Every variable in a program must have
>   a value before its value is used

It goes on to say the following about the initialization of reference types:

> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>     initialized with a default value when
>     it is created (§15.9, §15.10):
>
>   - *[removed information on irrelevant information]*
>   - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is `null`.

And finally, the follow about local variables:

> - A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must
>     be explicitly given a value before it
>     is used, by either initialization
>     (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a
>     way that can be verified by the
>     compiler using the rules for definite
>     assignment (§16).

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is a class variable, instance variable, or array component, it is initialized to `null` (since the default value for a reference type is `null`)

If the variable is a local variable, then it must be given a value explicitly (i.e. it has no default value in this case).

Answer (score 2):

A variable of type String is a reference variable. As an instance variable, it gets initialized to `null`, see [the specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5) for the discussion of other cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's `null` unless it's local, in which case it is technically uninitialized, but in fact you can't use it, for that reason, so the language is still type-safe. You can't deref a garbage pointer.

Answer (score 1):

null

Answer (score 0):

`String str=null` means that the str is a object of String class which is not pointing to anything...but when we talk abt memory allocation,memory will be allocated to str as soon as it comes into existence....u can check the amount of memory by using the profiling option in netbeans..

Answer (score 0):

the string value should be NULL in default , no need to initialize it.
string class objects are NULL by default only if they are defined as class level atttributes, otherwise string objects don't have any default value they need to be explicity initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable of type String is within a method, it would not automatically initialise. Otherwise it would be initialised with null as a value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any variable that is declared within a class is automatically initialized.
2. Any variable that is declared within a method must be initialized otherwise it will generate an error.
3. Strings are initialized to null,ints to 0 and so on..

Check this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more information...